# How to open a (unnamed) unix pipe in a java client

Tags: java, unix, posix, pipe

A server, written in C, creates an unnamed unix pipe using `pipe()` - i.e. a pair of fd's.
Then it starts a client passing one of fd's for communication.

Everything is straightforward if a client is written in C. The question is, how to open a pipe in a java client, given the fd?

A generic POSIX solution would be appreciated, but a Linux-specific one is good enough.

Comment: I would think if you fork the client with your pipe connected to stdin/stdout, it'd be available just as got any other program. Is that good enough?

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill - no, I need to use other pipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you can most easily use the pseudo files `/proc/PID/fd/N` to access the file descriptor `N` associated to process whose PID is `PID` (your server, in this case).